# Is it possible to declare a method as final in a class in Dart?

Tags: class, dart, methods, final

In Java one can declare a method within a class to prevent subclasses from overriding it.

For example:

```
class Foo {

   final void bar() {
     // some code here.
   }

}
```

Is there a similar construction in Dart?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`package:meta` provides a [`@nonVirtual` annotation](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/nonVirtual-constant.html) to disallow overriding methods.

Note that annotations just provide *hints* to `dart analyze`.  They won't actually prevent anything from violating the annotations, and they instead will cause warnings to be printed when analysis is performed.

If you want to disallow derived classes entirely (at least outside of the Dart library, which usually means outside of the `.dart` file), as of Dart 3.0, you can use the [`final` or `sealed` class modifiers](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers).  Unlike annotations, those modifiers will be enforced by the compiler.

Comment: Thanx. It turned out that I didn't need the annotation after all.

Comment: _They won't actually prevent anything from violating the annotations (...)_ This statement is a bit misleading. First, you can declare `invalid_override_of_non_virtual_member: error` in `analysis_options.yaml`, so it's an analysis error, not a warning. Second, you can build your build scripts and/or CI/CD pipeline to fail if analysis emits errors. It's very practical and _will_ prevent from violating these annotations.

Comment: Not to mention that analyzer warnings/errors are visible in Dart Analysis panel in Intellij IDEA, so there's a great chance that developers will spot them before build scripts and/or CI/CD pipeline fails.

Comment: @cubuspl42 `invalid_override_of_non_virtual_member: error` is misleading by providing a false sense of security.  It will generate an error *if you run the analyzer*, but nothing forces people to run the analyzer.  Even with a proper CI/CD pipeline, annotations cannot prevent someone else from extending your class in an undesired way *in some other package*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, code for Irn & Jamesdlin answer:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Foo { 
   @nonVirtual 
   void bar() {
     print("bar from Foo!");
   } 
}

class SubFoo extends Foo {
  @override
   void bar()  {
      print("bar from SubFoo");
   }
}
```

And you get the warning from Analyzer like this:

The member 'bar' is declared non-virtual in 'Foo' and can't be overridden in subclasses.dart(invalid_override_of_non_virtual_member)

Comment: This is what I wrote in my answer (minus the example).  As I noted there, the warning comes from the analyzer, not the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, jamesdlin, I just edited my anwser.